# Mongoengine deferencing happens after using select_related()

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

This could be a stupid question if my understanding about select_related() is completely wrong.

Here is the database design that I have.

```
class UserAccount(Document):
    first_name = StringField(max_length = 20)
    last_name = StringField(max_length = 20)
    user_name = StringField(max_length = 20) 
    friends = ListField(ReferenceField('self'))
```

And the queryset is:

```
u = UserAccount.objects.get(user_name="something").select_related()
```

I've passed the result in 'u' to the Django templates. So I tried this in the template.

```
{% for friend in u.friends %}
    {% for f in friend.friends %}
        {{ f.friends }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm able to see the friends of friends of my friends in the browser. Isn't the work of select_related() to stop the further dereferencing that's happening here?

Correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First a word of warning, this is not only a relational schema but a recursively relational one.  You could follow the relationships and end up loading **all** the `UserAccount` objects.

Remember there are **no joins** in MongoDB - so you are asking the client code (mongoengine) to perform in application joins for you - which means multiple queries and then assigning the results to the correct documents - thats expensive.  So please ask yourself "*is this the right tool for the job?*"

However, your observations are correct - by default [select_related()](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html?highlight=select_related#mongoengine.Document.select_related) only goes down a single relation so for a user object it will only dereference the first set of friends and not their friends.  You can change the depth by passing it to `select_related(max_depth=2)`.